# What to use with history api instead of hash to differentiate between sections on a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-history

I have this url:
domain/?budget=0-&pn=1

Now i have a button which clicks a special view on the same page. I have done it like:

domain/?budget=0-&pn=1#special

The problem is that i am implementing history api and change in hash is causing popstate to be triggered which is not good.

What should i use instead of hash for such situation with html5 history api?

Answer (score 0):

Using Single Page Applications (SPA The wiki definition is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)

where a single page acts as the host page for other content loaded on demand into the page. In this case, the use of page templates ensures that every page, at one time or another, acts as the content host as well as a content page.
[image]
depicts how the HTML pages are structured. Each has the required structure around the page along with a content container whose inner HTML is replaced with a fragment of HTML from a content page. The identifier in the URL represents the unique identifier of the page content that is loaded into the page.

What makes use of the history object’s new members so valuable is that even though you can programmatically change the browser location without posting back to the server, at the same time that updated location is nothing more than a regular URL, which can be shared, copied or bookmarked. This means that you need to make sure your application works just as well upon the initial request of the page as it does when JavaScript is used to fetch the page.

[image]

demonstrates how Page 1 is affected by navigating to Page 2 using the history.pushState function. The overall structure of the page is preserved and after the response of an Ajax call is received, only the page fragment is injected into the content container. Notice how the page title remains the same, but the URL and content in the container reflect content from Page 2.

Consider though if you refresh the page after you navigated to Page 2 using pushState. Figure 3 shows how the page, when refreshed, keeps the correct URL and preserves the page content, but the page title reflects that it was served directly from Page 2.
[image]

This behavior is achieved by all pages having the same layout structure but include identifiers in the markup to specify the content fragment in the page. This is the same spirit in which a normal client/server web application would serve full HTML pages upon a standard GET request of the page, but then use a service in conjunction with an Ajax call to only update specific parts of the page.

Remember

As with most areas of new HTML5 capabilities, the functionality found in the new history object is available via a polyfill library that can fill in the gaps for older browsers or those that are yet to implement the standard.